# Get first element of ResultTable[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, time

These codes:

```
String genType = FileConstants.CHANGE_CYCLE;
ResultTable[] genericCode = RTManager.getRTCsmGenericCodesDecodeList(genType);
String genCode = Arrays.toString(genericCode);
```

Returns these values:

```
genCode = [[code=22:00:00]

[dCode=Cut-off time for change bill_cycle if existing cycle_close_date=activity_date]]
```

Question: how do i get only `'22:00:00'` and convert it as `Time datatype`?

Comment: First step to do is to avoid `Arrays.toString` and use `genericCode[0].toString()` instead. Please let us know what that returns so we can give you the best assistance with the next step.

Comment: What makes you think you want a result of type `Time`? That class is long outdated and was always poorly designed. You are probably much better off with `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

If the item in the  ResultTable array has a toString() and it produces string then you can get it like this.

genericCode[0].toString().split("=")[1]

---

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String time = "22:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Date date;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(time);
            System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: from this, how can i convert it to time with format `DateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  ` ?

Comment: i'm getting  error: `unreported exception java.text.ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` for `Date date = sdf.parse(time);`

Comment: how come printing date resulted to: `Thu Jan 01 22:00:00 IST 1970` ? although `sdf` is just `HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Don't print date directly. Print as I showed in the code.   sdf.format(date)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @dcdum2018 That’s just one piece of the trouble with the old date and time classes, there isn’t a class for a time of day without date and without time zone. So what you are really getting is a point in time, probably Jan 1, 1970 at 16:30 UTC. As long as you are in Asia/Kolkata time zone this will print as `Thu Jan 01 22:00:00 IST 1970`.